# When passing `label_mode="binary"`, there must be exactly 2 class_names. Received: class_names=[]

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning and now I'm trying to classify skin diseases. I've tried this code in google colab however it gives me an error. **When passing `label_mode="binary"`, there must be exactly 2 class_names. Received: class_names=[]**

[MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E852h.png)

Comment: write detail of training data

Comment: Please do **not** post code screenshots; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If label_mode = 'binary' but the length of class_name is not equal to 2 then you get these errors and this same thing happens in your case.

So you can go with two options:

1. label_mode = 'int'  (i.e the labels are encoded as integers)
2. label_mode = 'categorical'  (i.e the labels are encoded as a categorical vector)

NOTE: selection of label_mode depend upon nature of label in the dataset.

for more information you can check this: [enter link description here](https://keras.io/api/data_loading/image/)